# ¿Por qué no me funciona esta llamada a Ajax para obtener la fecha y hora actual en aplicación ASP?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy realizando una aplicación ASP, en la que necesito que aparezca la fecha y hora actual en un campo de texto, a la hora de dar de alta. Su código ASP es el siguiente:

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="LabelFechaHora" class="lbl_izq">Fecha y Hora</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="FECHAHORA" id="FECHAHORA" runat="server" class="text_gris_claro" size="50"
                        maxlength="50" readonly />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Para la llamada Ajax, he creado una función que devuelve la fecha y hora actual en otro archivo:

```
 <WebMethod()> _


 Public Shared Function ObtenerFechaActual() As String
        Dim fechaActual As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        Return fechaActual
    End Function
```

Y función Ajax es la siguiente:

```
function actualizarCampoTexto() {
        var valorNuevo = null;
        var llamada = $.ikt_ajax_obj.inicializar();
        llamada.pagina = "Utilidades.aspx/ObtenerFechaActual";
        llamada.async = false;

        llamada.correcto = function(response) {
            valorNuevo = response.responseText;
        };

        llamada.error = function(obj) {
            console.log("Error en la llamada AJAX: " + obj);
        };

        llamada.enviar();

        // Colocar el valor obtenido en el campo de texto
        $('#FECHAHORA').val(valorNuevo);

    }
```

Dicha función es llamada dentro del document.ready, al final. El problema es que no pasa nada, y creo que he seguido todos los pasos. ¿Hay alquien que pueda decirme donde está el fallo en mi código? ¿Me he saltado algún paso?

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: No conozco ASP, por tanto no podría ayudarte con propiedad en esta pregunta. Pero esto es muy llamativo: `llamada.async = false;` ¿Por qué impides que la llamada sea asíncrona? Javascript y Ajax en consecuencia, trabajan por defecto de forma asíncrona para permitir que mientras esta llamada y otras se completan, se puedan seguir procesando otras cosas. Si tú haces que la llamada sea síncrona, todo se bloqueará, hasta que esta llamada sea procesada, porque JS es de un solo hilo. [Esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) es de obligada lectura.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias aspectos a revisar que pueden estar afectando, te los compato:

- Checa tu WebMethod: Asegúrate de que ObtenerFechaActual esté bien
  configurado y accesible. Tiene que ser un WebMethod y estar en un
  lugar donde tu AJAX lo pueda llamar.
- Ruta del WebMethod: Ojo con la ruta en llamada.pagina. Si
  Utilidades.aspx no está en la misma carpeta que tu script AJAX, la
  ruta tiene que ser ajustada.
- Respuesta del WebMethod: Los WebMethods normalmente devuelven JSON.
  Cuando recibes la respuesta en tu función correcto, puede que tengas
  que hacer algo para obtener la fecha en el formato correcto.
- Llamada AJAX Síncrona: Estás usando async = false, lo que hace la
  llamada síncrona. Esto puede hacer que la interfaz se congele
  mientras espera. Mejor hazlo asíncrono.
- Debugging: Usa console.log para ver qué está pasando en tu código. Te
  puede ayudar a identificar dónde está el fallo.
- Script en Documento: Confirma que actualizarCampoTexto realmente se
  está llamando dentro de $(document).ready.
- Errores en la Consola: Echa un vistazo a la consola del navegador. Si
  hay errores de JavaScript o con la solicitud AJAX, te darán pistas.
- Respuesta del Servidor: Con las herramientas de desarrollo del
  navegador, puedes ver qué está respondiendo el servidor a tu AJAX.
  Esto te dice si el problema es del lado del servidor o del cliente.

Espero que esto te ayude a encontrar el fallo. Si sigues atorado, cualquier detalle extra podría ayudar a dar con la solución. ¡Suerte!